# How do I register custom information to be sent when $disconnect route is executed using a WebSocket API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible with Websocket AWS API to register custom information to be sent when disconnect event is triggered by the client?

> The connection can be closed by the server or by the client. As the
> connection is already closed when it is executed, $disconnect is a
> best-effort event. API Gateway will try its best to deliver the
> $disconnect event to your integration, but it cannot guarantee
> delivery.

I understand that $disconnect is a best-effort event and could not reach to the integration, but for most cases it probably will so I would like to be able to send some information to the lambda about the user or device that disconnects and not to make another database call to get userId/deviceId for a given connectionID.

I have checked the request context of disconnect event (which contains metadata such as sourceIp) but none of the information from there I find reliable to do this mapping.

Comment: did you find a solution for that ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, not

Comment: Most likely, it's not possible.